# how to redirect with apache

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I need to do a redirect a url to another with Apache, but only if url match with `issues/[0-9]+`.

example:

```
http://mysite.net/issues/44
```

to

```
http://mysite.net/dashboard/issues/44
```

**UPDATE:**

I put following lines (without `#`) in .htaccess but not work:

```
# Redirect ^/issues/(.*)$ /dashboard/issues/$1
# AliasMatch ^/issues/(.*)$ /dashboard/issues/$1
# Alias /issues/(.*) /dashboard/issues/$1
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple google search will show you that is exactly what [mod_alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html) is for.

> mod_alias is designed to handle simple URL manipulation tasks.

In your case you can use the power of regular expressions.

Such as:

```
RedirectMatch /issues/([0-9]+) /dashboard/issues/$1
```

Comment: does this work `RedirectMatch /issues/([0-9]+) /dashboard/issues/$1`